# Correct format for making own data to feed into sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a project to classify types of objects based on some measurements taken with time.
I have two types of objects. One is SN (1) one is not SN (0)
I am about to start collecting data to feed my ML machine but before I do, I would like to check that the way I want to do it is correct as this is my first ml project.

I want to feed in a table that has format similar to the example below.

[image: example data]

I plan on using pythons sklearn package and random forest to classify which of the two classes data i give it fits into.
Is it that straight forward or do i need special columns with other information for sklearn to read it?

Comment: Pandas DataFrame work fine with sklearn.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Thanks it worked beautifully

Comment: alright I wrote a answer from the comment. Do you mind marking it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas DataFrame work fine with sklearn.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html